# Crystal Report issues for rpt file not load after iis publish

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, iis-7.5

First `report.Load("C:\Report\exam.rpt")`
this path is outside website folder `C:\Report\exam.rpt`  Report will be Generated.

but `report.Load(Server.mapPath("~\Report\exam.rpt"))` geting some error

> Load report failed.Stack:: at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)`

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I don't think `~\Report\exam.rpt` translates to physical path C:\Report\exam.rpt.  The ~ likely translates to the web application phsical path.

Answer (score 0):

Server.mapPath() takes your application path. Provide full path to report.Load() or place your .rpt file in Your Project solution.